# Can't be used with a custom content view in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-listview

i need use the method

`setEmptyText();`

But i use fragment of screen and when i try run my app, the error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view

Is returned to me, i read that it is caused because i'm using Fragment screen.

`public class ManejoFragment extends ListFragment ()`

Folow the example of method that returns this error:

```java
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(null);
        View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.device_list_header, null, false);
        getListView().addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        setEmptyText("Inicializando...");

        ((TextView) getListView().getEmptyView()).setTextSize(18);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

All methods that use the `setEmptyText()` return the same error.

Comment: Can you show the layout file for `ManejoFragment` and `onCreateView()` method on that fragment?

Comment: How i'll test it?